# div above other divs

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to order my divs in such a way, but I cannot find a solution (mainly there is a problem with the yellow box):

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <header>
          <div id="header-top"></div>
          <div id="header-bottom" class="clearfix">
        </header>

       <div style="clear:both"></div>

       <div id="content">

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    header {padding: 0;margin:0; position: relative; z-index: 1;}

  #header-top {
        height: 22px;
        background-color: #a68572;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #header-top p {text-align: right;}

    #header-bottom {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #logo {
        position:relative;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;
        z-index: 30;
        top:-80px;
        left: 50px;
    }

    #content {position: relative;z-index: 1;}
```

As you see I've been tryin to do something with positions and z-indexes but not to well ;)

And, by the way, how can I get rid of this white space between header-bottom and content? All of the paddings and margins are set to 0, so I don't know why they are not directly next to each other.

Comment: Why do you clear ? You have no floating element. I try to make a fiddle

Comment: Well, I've been trying different solutions and after I've added clearing then the header-bottom appeared correctly.

Comment: best to use a [clearfix](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/) for clearing then you don't have additional markup. Also you haven't shown where your logo is in the html above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put .header-bottom in position:relative and .logo in position: absolute. Then use top and left to place it where you want. Example :

```css
header {
  height: 120px;
}

.header-top {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.header-bottom {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
section {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-top"></div>
  <div class="header-bottom">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</header>

<section></section>
```

Comment: You can laugh but it doesn't work for me :/ Take a look: http://kama.besaba.com/test/index.html

Comment: It is because you mix both of our codes ;) You use classes in the markup and you target it with # in your CSS (# is for IDs). Change all the # in your markup by . (dot). Or you can change all "class" in HTML by "id". But its common to use only classes in CSS and keep IDs for JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: I've been editing the wrong style.css ^^' Thank you very much! And also for the "class" tip. I've always though it's better to use IDs for unique elements.